# Does GraphDiff work in a database first scenario?

Tags: graphdiff

I'm using Entity Framework in an application with a existing SQL Server db. Can GraphDiff be used in a database first scenario, assuming I use the POCO Entity Generator?

Comment: That should work if you're using the DbContext API, but I've never actually tried it..